# Boost Date going back in time

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

Hello I would like to go back in time using `boost::Date_time`. For example set the date to the one from 10 days ago. I tried using `day_iterator` but with no luck so far.
Here is My attempt:

```
boost::gregorian::date dateGenerator(int howManyDays)
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();

    boost::gregorian::date date(now.date());
    boost::gregorian::day_iterator dayIterator(data,-1);

    for (; howManyDays != 0; ++dayIterator)
    {
        howManyDays--;
    }
    return date;

}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Hello, boost::Date_time is not enough to go back in time, you need a full-functioning time machine for it. Sorry, couldn't resist. Now on topic: what is your actual goal? Do you simply need to subtract one date from another and get the result which is in the past? Also what about using `std::chrono`?

Comment: Your code does not work because the `day_iterator` does not modify the original date, it creates new date objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract a [date duration](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#duration_intro) from a date by using the [- operator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_operators):

```
date_duration dd(howManyDays);
date d2 = date - dd;
return d2;
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot mate